# Converting string "1 + 2" to integer

Tags: java, string, int

Is it possible to convert a String such as 1 + 2 into an integer that equals 3?

I know I can use valueOf() to get the value of individual numbers

```
String test1 = "1";
String test2 = "2";
int test3 = Integer.valueOf(test1);
int test4 = Integer.valueOf(test2);

int answer = test3 + test4;
System.out.println(answer);
```

but is it possible to convert "1 + 2" to 3 in one step instead of two?

Comment: No, not with standard java libraries.

Comment: Not with usual libraries. Although, you could split the string by ' ' and then simply add valueOf(split[0]) + valueOf(split[2]).

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java

Comment: @svz That's not true. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @svz unless you're willing to invoke a compiler and a classloader, you mean?

Comment: @Jeffrey, my bad, didn't know there was such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java comes packaged with [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29).

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class RhinoExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine rhino = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        Double result = (Double) rhino.eval("1 + 2");
        Integer i = result.intValue();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: He has two strings, `"1"` and `"2"`.  Does `rhino` handle this?  Your example seems to suggest `rhino` expects a single string with math operators within the string.

Comment: @rhgrif Rhino is a fully functional JavaScript implementation. You can use [`put`](http://tinyurl.com/lf55j6t) to create variables and process it that way or you could do `val1 + " + " + val2` before invoking `eval`.

Comment: @Jeffrey Now does this have to go in public static void main? Or is there another way to throw the ScriptException from another method?

Comment: @user1984712 You can put this in any method you wish. You can either make that method throw the `ScriptException` or you can use a [`try-catch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use javax.script.ScriptEngineManager and javax.script.ScriptEngine; Check this post [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Answer (score 0):

The standard java libraries does not allow you to do this. However as Jeff Storey answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java) you may try like this:

```
ScriptEngineManager mg= new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mg.getEngineByName("js");        
Object result = engine.eval("1+2");
```

However if you dont want to use the above method the best you can do is this:

```
String test1 = "1";
String test2 = "2";
System.out.println((Integer.valueOf(test1)+Integer.valueOf(test2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printStringSum(String s1, String s2) {
    int i1 = Integer.valueOf(s1);
    int i2 = Integer.valueOf(s2);
    val = i1 + i2;
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Now where  ever it is in the code that you're wanting to do what's posted in the original code, just call this method:

```
printStringSum("1", "2");
```

---

However, you can improve this further by making the method expect an array of Strings.  Within the method body, iterate through the string, taking the value and `+=`-ing it to `val`, then printing `val` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's necessary for memory reasons, Id stick with the way you have it, for debugging reasons especially if test1 and test2 are eventually some kind of user input.

```
String test1 = "1";
String test2 = "2";
System.out.println((Integer.valueOf(test1)+Integer.valueOf(test2)));
```

This works as well

```
String test1 = "1";
String test2 = "2";
int answer = (Integer.valueOf(test1)+Integer.valueOf(test2));
System.out.println(answer);
```

if its REALLY necessary to limit the number of lines and you can gaurentee that test1 and test2 are going to be "1" and "2" then just use:

```
System.out.println((Integer.valueOf("1")+Integer.valueOf("2")));
```